# AuthorizeCore not working for custom authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use a custom Authorize attribute in my application to handle request from Clients and Administrators.

I've used the same approach in a different application where the only difference was the authentication type. One being Microsoft Account based and this one being Federated Services based.

I've set a break point in my override of the AuthorizationCore method, my problem is that this is only getting fired once when the user tries to access the application for the first time, it will then redirect the user to the login page. After this it does not get fired again. I need it to fire every time a user accesses the controller/action so we can check if the user has the correct role, which in my understanding is the what the Authorize attribute is for.

My code:

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Role required by the Action or Controller
    /// </summary>
    public UserRole RequireRole { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Authorization Logic
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        //Result = new AuthorizationResult();
        bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                ApplicationUser user = context.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress.Equals(httpContext.User.Identity.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            }


            // ... Check if user has the required role
        }

        return isAuthorized;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Redirect the user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Handle the request if the user does not have the required role

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I'm using the Attribute as follows

```
    [AuthorizeUser(RequireRole = Core.Models.Users.UserRole.User)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How are you using the `AuthorizeUserAttribute`? Please post some code examples.

Comment: Where are you setting `isAuthorized` to false?

Comment: @NightOwl888 I added the implementation

Comment: @S.Dav that is just the basic layout, I haven't added any logic yet

Comment: As it is now, once the user is logged in it will always return true since `isAuthorized` is not set to false anywhere

Comment: @S.Dav I know, but that is not my problem, problem currently is that the code only gets fired once, where it should be firing every time I access the "Index" action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like kicking myself having to admit this one

My code was working perfectly, the issue was that the authentication provider redirects me to my https site after it has been authenticated, what I didn't realise was the port where it redirects me. The port it was redirecting to was the test application in my IIS and not the dev application in my IIS Express. doh!

Comment: I was facing a similar situation with a redirect and this helped a lot.  Thanks!